# $\| U+\|V\|_r\|_m =\| U+V \|_m$ if and only if $m=r=2$.

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, normed-spaces

Let $\|U \|_p = \left( E[|U|^p] \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$.

Is the following result statement true?

> Let $U$ and $V$ bet two independent, symmetric, non-degenerate random
>   variables.  Then, \begin{align*} \| U+\|V\|_r\|_m =\| U+V \|_m
>  \end{align*}  if and only if $r=m=2$.

Note that the "if"  directions is trivial since
\begin{align}
E[(U + \|V\|_2)^2]= E[U^2]+E[V^2]=E[(U+V)^2].
\end{align}

The question is how to show the "only if" direction.

I also feel that this should have come up somewhere. For example, is it related somehow to the fact that $L^2$ norm is the only $L_p$ norm induced by the inner product?  Anyway, this is just a thought and the question is not about inner products.

Comment: but the problem doesn't even state that m and r are integers.

Comment: @novavita Yes. I don't want to make this assumption. I said that using binomial theorem was the only thing I thought of, and that requires the assumption that $m$ is an integer.

Comment: with non-degenerate you mean not constant?

Comment: @supinf Yes. Non-degenerate=non-constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fact seems to be false. Let $U$ and $V$ be random variables with support over $\{-1,1\}$.

- Since $|V|=1$, conclude that $||V||_{r}=1$. Therefore, $|U+||V||_{r}|=|U+1|$. Since $U$ has a symmetric distribution, $P(|U+1|=0)=P(|U+1|=2)=0.5$. Conclude that
  $P(|U+||V||_{r}|=0)=P(|U+||V||_{r}|=2)=0.5$
- Since $U$ and $V$ are symmetric and independent $P(|U+V|=0)=P(|U+V|=2)=0.5$.

Since $|U+||V||_{r}|$ and $|U+V|$ have the same distribution,
conlude that $||U+||V||_{r}||_{m}=||U+V||_{m}$. 
Note that $m$ and $r$ were arbitrary.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you. I found this same counterexample earlier today.  I think for this to hold we have to assume that $U$ and $V$ are unbounded. Just so you know you will get the bounty.