# $f_m(x)= E[|V+x|^m]-|x|^m$ is constant iff $m=2$.

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Let $V$ be a symmetric non-degenerate random variable. Now define
\begin{align}
f_m(x)= E\big[|V+x|^m\big]-|x|^m,
\end{align}

Is the following claim true:

> $f_m(x)$ is constant if and only if $m=2$.

Clear for $m=2$ we have that $f_2(x)=E[V^2]$ and is constant for all $x$.

I am interested in the other direction.  To show that the function is non-constant we can show that the derivative of $f_m(x)$ is non-zero. The derivative is given by
\begin{align}
f^{\prime}(x)= m \left( E\big[|V+x|^{m-1} {\rm sign}(V+x)\big] -\text{sign}(x) |x|^{m-1} \right),   x\neq 0. 
 \end{align}

However, I am not sure how to show that $f^{\prime}(x)$ has values  such that $f^{\prime}(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2501815/u-v-r-m-uv-m-if-and-only-if-m-r-2 this question looks similar ;)

Comment: @supinf Sure. There is a degree of relation between the two.

Comment: Consider the limit when $x\to\infty$. Then $$|V+x|^m=|x|^m+mx|x|^{m-2}V+\tfrac12m(m-1)|x|^{m-2}V^2+o(|x|^{m-2})$$ hence $$f_m(x)=\tfrac12m(m-1)|x|^{m-2}E(V^2)+o(|x|^{m-2})$$ This does not depend on $x$ only if $m=2$ (ok) or $m=1$.  But maybe you already found an argument (there are some) to eliminate the case $m=1$?

Comment: @Did Thanks for the method.  For $m=1$ $f^{\prime}_m(x)= E[ {\rm sign}(V+x)]- {\rm sign}(x)= E[ 1_{V+x>0} -1 _{V+x\le 0}]-{\rm sign}(x)= P[V+x>0]-P[V+x\le 0]-{\rm sign}(x) =1 - 2 P[V+x\le 0]-{\rm sign}(x)= 1-{\rm sign}(x)- 2F_V(-x)$.

Comment: Moreover, take $x>0$ in which case  $f^{\prime}_m(x)= -2F_V(-x)$